# ffmpeg_kit_flutter commands work on some devices but not on some other devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I have been trying to create videos from a series of images with similar formats using the ffmpeg_kit_flutter package. While using the package, I have encountered an issue where the video generation works on certain devices but not on my Android device (Android 10). Below are the code snippets I have been using for the video generation process.

I have invoked the `videoCreator()` function in the following manner.

```dart
 Future<void> videoCreator() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      print('generation initiated');
      outputPath = File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/output123.mp4').path;
      String commandToExecute = '-framerate ${framerate.toInt()} -i '
          '\'$videoDirectory/%d.jpeg\''
          ' -q:v 1 -y $outputPath';
      print('$commandToExecute');
      await FFmpegKit.execute(commandToExecute).then((session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
```

The output from debug console is as follows:

```
I/flutter ( 5871): generation initiated
I/flutter ( 5871): -framerate 12 -i '/data/user/0/com.example.test_project/app_flutter/1/%d.jpeg' -q:v 1 -y /storage/emulated/0/Download/output123.mp4
I/flutter ( 5871): Loading ffmpeg-kit-flutter.
D/ffmpeg-kit-flutter( 5871): FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.flutter.FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin@8324d61 started listening to events on io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler$EventSinkImplementation@50da4a8.
```

And also to determine whether the video generation was successful or not, the code checks the return code obtained from the `session`. If the return code indicates success (using the `ReturnCode.isSuccess()` method), it prints "Success!" to the console else prints "Failure!" wrt to the following conditions given:

```dart
        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
          print("Success!");
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
            status = true;
          });
        } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
          print("Cancelled!");
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
            status = false;
          });
        } else {
          print("Failure!");
          print(await session.getFailStackTrace());
          print("Failure!");
          print(await session.getOutput());
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
            status = false;
          });
        }
```

But I continue to receive "Failure!" messages in the debug console.

```
I/flutter ( 5871): Failure!
I/flutter ( 5871): LightThemeSet
I/flutter ( 5871): null
I/flutter ( 5871): Failure!
```

I attempted the following approaches to resolve the issue:

1. Tried changing the output path for the generated video.
2. Tried updating the required storage permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Currently the permissions include the standard `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions used for the older android versions and the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission used for newer versions
3. Tested the app on various Android emulators with different configurations where it worked properly.

Any sort of help would be appreciated!
Warm regards

Comment: https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/issues/215